# Jenkins Kubernetes Runner/Agents fails

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, bitnami, agent, runner

I am running a Bitnami Jenkins pod on K8s. Agents shall be scheduled within the same Namespace, which works good.

When running, it checks out git, pod starts, followed by following exceptions at Jenkins Built job:

```
commit message: "Update deployment.yaml"
 > git rev-list --no-walk ffba5471c965178f7f2f036076239ad1df692475 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse ffba5471c965178f7f2f036076239ad1df692475~
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Prepare)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpWebSocketImpl$1.onFailure(OkHttpWebSocketImpl.java:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.kt:592)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.checkUpgradeSuccess$okhttp(RealWebSocket.kt:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:170)
    ... 4 more
Failed to start websocket connection: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:129)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:122)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReady(Utils.java:174)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReadyOrFail(Utils.java:184)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.setupConnectionToPod(PodOperationsImpl.java:365)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.exec(PodOperationsImpl.java:286)
at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:448)
at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:335)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:176)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:326)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor586.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpWebSocketImpl$1.onFailure(OkHttpWebSocketImpl.java:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.kt:592)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: waiting here
```

looks like `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'` makes trouble; I Wonder where this comes for. Any suggestion for debugging the issue? Don't know which resource might cause it... pod is fine, jenkins is fine, git is fine.. :-/

Comment: The 403 Forbidden is an issue of authentication. are you sure you are using the correct username and password.? did you set a Jenkins user as a root? It will be great to post the k8s API server logs to check if the issue is related to Auth or related to a network issue.

Comment: Have you done any Jenkins or plugins version updates?
What version of Kubernetes plugins are you using? Jenkins version?

Comment: Its a fresh bitnami/jenkins installation via HELM. It runs Jenkins 2.387.1 in combination with bitnami/jenkins-agent and jenkins/jenkins-agent; both having the same issue. Plugin-wise its OpenID Connect Authentication (works), Kubernetes (looks good), Pipeline, Pipeline: Multibranch and Git. I noticed, that an pipeline-echo "test" works within lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest. Any kubectl fails. When exec -ti  into the container, I do have API access and can create namespaces and stuff... right service account with permissions.. Thinking about connectivity jenkins <> k8s-kubectl

Comment: echo "Testing the pipeline"

sh "kubectl apply -f ./iac/namespace.yaml"
Example:
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Prepare)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Testing the pipeline
[Pipeline] sh
Failed to start websocket connection: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.